# HTML video tag is not working in Eclipse IDE

Tags: html, eclipse

[image]

I want to display a video on my Homepage. I have used the following code:-

```
<video class="center" autoplay muted>
            <source src="Images/Introduction.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            <source src="Images/Introduction.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            Your browser does not support the <code>video</code> tag </video>
```

But the video is not displayed on my HomePage when I run my project.

Comment: SO recommends to post [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Examples](/help/mcve)(aka mcve). Also, how your question relates to Eclipse?

Comment: Because I am working in Eclipse IDE and this code works fine in NetBeans IDE, so I wanted to know the issue with Eclipse in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried your code in my editor it is working, I think you're not giving the proper source for a video that is why it won't work.

Comment: Hi, I have created a folder in the project named "Images" and have attached all images and video to that and have also added the Images folder to the build path but still, nothing gets displayed. Try adding a folder and then add an image to it. Pls let me know if it works and do have a look on the screenshot of it which I have attached to my original question.

Comment: Please once you check whatever the videos or images your using those all are present in your images folder or not. Because again I have to use your code with video and image its working. and you should also check the file extension.

Comment: Thank you, but it worked. There was a problem in the path.

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at this for reference http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp.

If it's not working check the path of the file

```css
video {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<video autoplay loop muted>
 <source src="http://www.icutpeople.com/wp-content/themes/icutpeople/assets/video/waynesworld.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried the same but it still doesn't work

Comment: did you check the path?

Comment: Please check the above snippet. I have edited that with some video . Let me know if it works

Comment: Your above code works fine with that video but when I give the path of my Introduction.mp4 video file nothing gets displayed. I have created an Images folder in which I have pasted all the images and video but none of them is working. I have also added the Images folder to the build path still nothing worked. I have edited my above question and have added a screenshot of it. So, pls do have a look. Thanks